# How to set the initial value for the sub form group?

Tags: angular

My code resides [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utuyav?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

I have a nested form group.

When the web page refresh, the initial value of callTreeEntryForm.value:

```
callTreeEntryForm.value={ "attributesForm": null }
```

My expected result as the following:

```
callTreeEntryForm.value={ "attributesForm": { "division": "" } }
```

How can I achieve this?

Because of the callTreeEntry is null during in the constructor of AttributesForm object,
I have tried to modify the code in the ngOnInit method, unfortunately, these modifications not working.

**I would be grateful if the modification can be done in the AttributesForm object.**

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the initial value for the `attributesForm`

Change

```
this.callTreeEntryForm = this.fb.group({ attributesForm: new FormControl() });
```

To

```
this.callTreeEntryForm = this.fb.group({ attributesForm: new FormControl({ "division": "" }) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just init your `FormControl` with the correct value `new FormControl({ "division": "" })`

```
this.callTreeEntryForm = this.fb.group(
         { attributesForm: new FormControl({ "division": "" });
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the content of registerOnChange from :

```
registerOnChange(fn: any) {
 this.attributesForm.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
 console.log("registerOnChange");
}
```

to

```
registerOnChange(fn: any) {
 this.attributesForm.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
 this.division.setValue(this.callTreeEntry.division);
 console.log("registerOnChange");
}
```

It works.
The working solution resides [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qrzfce).